# On manjaro linux eclipse ide throws a null pointer exception whenever I try to make a new project

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

So when I try to create a new project (any project type) eclipse just produces an error that says:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerExeption
> ```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Comment: ok i will do that soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much more helpful if you included as much detail about the issue as you can. Next time, put a little more effort when you ask for help, which includes doing more research. Based on what you gave, I found several sources in the first 5 links of a google search for `Eclipse new project null pointer`.

I'm going to try and format this well so that others who have the same issue have a nicely formatted reference.

### Possible Solutions to Eclipse NullPointerException

[From here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=212229). Might be the best resource to look at since Manjaro is based on archlinux, AND this thread is relatively new.

Transcription of user `Misto`'s solution in case link goes dead:

> Doesn't look familiar, but I've had my share of problems with SWT (Eclipse's widget toolkit) and GTK3, you can try forcing SWT back to GTK2 with the environment variable SWT_GTK3=0. Maybe this helps.

Other link(s) detailing the same problem:

[Eclipse Forums, May 12th 2016](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1077400/)
Transcription from user Felix Dorner:

> Try this:
>   - Open the error log view. (Window->Show View->Error Log)
>   - Clean the log (there is double x in its toolbar)
>   - Create the project
>   - Double click on the error that should appear in the log
>   - Copy the contents of the stack trace dialog and paste here.
>   Felix

After the problem persists with another error exception, Felix again replies with this:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.gtk_switch_page(TabFolder.java:570)
>
> These two lines are sufficient for google to find you a solution ;)`